# TextView weird behavior

Tags: java, android

I got a weird behavior in my textview. When i load a large text, and you need to scroll dawn if i refresh whit new text the same textview the "focus of the scroll" still be down and I dont know how to fix it...

So my textView is like this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTexto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:maxLines= "5000"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"            
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

And the definition in the Activity is this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_text);

        texto = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("memorization");
        this.inicializar(texto); 
             .........`

private void inicializar(String texto){
    txtv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txtTexto);
    txtv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());      
    txtv.setText(texto);
}
```

I Change the "texto" and I call the textview like this

```
        boton.setText(R.string.animar);
        this.inicializar(texto_memorizado);
```

Someone can help me please? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: boton.setText(R.string.animar); what is boton here ?

Comment: Sorry that boton is the boton that you click to refresh the textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:id="@+id/textView1"
```

Since your text id is this try this,

```
private void inicializar(String texto){
    txtv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txtv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());      
    txtv.setText(texto);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Now I look like a idiot,

My correct textview is this one 
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTexto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:maxLines= "5000"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"            
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />